# Looping through folders

Tags: automation, uipath

How do I loop through folders inside an if statement. I want to tell the robot to search for filepath + row.item(0) + either one or double space + row.item(1).tostring? Some of the folders have double spaces and some have single space. Help is much appreciated.

Best regards

Comment: That's just a programming logic problem. Why dont you use regex to match LHS and RHS ? What is there in row.item(i)?

Comment: Row.item(0) is client number and the other is client name. I have tried using \s{1,} but it did not work. Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to recursively get folders you can use the below method

[`GetDirectories(String, String, SearchOption)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=netframework-4.8)

If you use the following parameters you should be able to find your folders, the top method will return folders with one space the one below will return folders with two spaces.

`Directory.GetDirectories(
    "C:\",
    filepath + row.item(0) + " " + row.item(1).tostring,
    SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

`Directory.GetDirectories(
    "C:\",
    filepath + row.item(0) + "  " + row.item(1).tostring,
    SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

To combine this into a single line of code that can be used within an assign you can use the following.

`Directory.GetDirectories("C:\",filepath + row.item(0) + " " + row.item(1).tostring,SearchOption.AllDirectories).AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories("C:\",filepath + row.item(0) + "  " + row.item(1).tostring,SearchOption.AllDirectories))`

This will extract on list of directories with one space in then add the second list of directories to it with the double spaces in. This will give you a single list containing folders that match either of the search strings

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like:

```
filepath + row.item(0).Trim() + " " + row.item(1).tostring.Trim()
```

Rename all the sub-folders under `filepath/*` and correct their names with a single space between name before applying above solution.

Another approach is, to use `try-catch` mechanism. If you are sure about these 2 conditions only - `try` with single space - if throws an error try with double space in the `catch` block.

Comment: I tried that one but it did not work. I figured it out by using double if statements and a single path exists before that. Thank you for your time.